# Why JavaScript returns [object Object] from valueOf() instead of [object]?

Tags: javascript

Is there a specific reason that JavaScript returns  [object Object] as a return value from valueOf() method?

Why not only [object] but [object Object] ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The second `Object` is the interface the object implements. For example, `document.body.valueOf()` would return `[object HTMLBodyElement]`.

Comment: +1 Good answer. Also, try simply `alert(valueOf)` you get `[object global]`

Comment: But is there any case that the first one won't be 'object' but something else -as everything is object in JavaScript?

Comment: @pencilCake Good question. By default not (it's simple to look how valueOf() behaves with strings, functions, arrays, etc.), but you're able to rewrite valueOf. `String.prototype.valueOf = function() { return "[foo Bar]"; };` causes that `"qux".valueOf()` would return `[foo Bar]`.

Comment: that means the first object is redundant?